# How to port a midsize .net 4.0 asp mvc4 VS 2012 solution(8 projects) to MonoDevelop 3.0.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, monodevelop

I want to try port a midsize .net 4.0 asp mvc4 solution(8 projects)  to MonoDevelop. I am using linux mint 14.

Can someone tell me the steps?